# How to append a link to gwtbootstrap 3 InputField

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I want to do this in html:

```
<div class="input-group" id="name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="none" id="name">None</a></span>
</div>
```

I try this in GWT Bootstrap:

```
<b:InputGroup>
    <b:TextBox b:id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
    <b:InputGroupAddon>
        <b:Anchor ui:field="noName" text="None"/>
    </b:InputGroupAddon>
</b:InputGroup>
```

But thus I get the error:

```
Illegal child <b:Anchor text='Name' ui:field='noName'> in a text-only context. Perhaps you are trying to use unescaped HTML where text is required, as in a HasText widget?: <b:InputGroupAddon> (:56)
```

Why? b:Anchor implements HasText interface.

My aim is to add a link on which, when a user clicks input will fill value NONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HasText` bit is about `InputGroupAddon`, not `Anchor`. "Text-only context" (implied by implementing `HasText`) means you can only put, well, text into that widget. Either through the `text` property (`<b:InputGroupAddon text='Name' />`) or inside the tags (`<b:InputGroupAddon>Name</b:InputGroupAddon>`) - those declarations are equivalent. You can't put unescaped HTML or widgets in such a context.

For your use case, I'd recommend using buttons (as the Bootstrap docs suggest):

```xml
<b:InputGroup>
  <b:TextBox b:id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  <b:InputGroupButton>
    <b:Button ui:field="noName" text="None" />
  </b:InputGroupButton>
</b:InputGroup>
```

See [the demo](https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#inputGroups) to see it in action. You can easily style it to your needs (maybe no text and just an `icon = "ERASER"`).